# Rx Concurrent Schedules with Locking

Tags: c#, unit-testing, system.reactive

I am struggling with Rx yet again. This time I am having an issue with Observable.Interval.

My requirements are:

- I need to run data collection every 1 second.
- I need to check for changes to parameters every 5 seconds.
- I cannot be collecting data while I'm checking for changes.
- If data collection OR check for changes takes longer than 1 second dont queue those ticks up, just skip them.
- If a change check tick occurs while a data collection is in progress, i want it to wait to execute.

I have tried using Observables for the intervals and have found that by default Intervals will queue up missed ticks! Finally after creating a whole console app, I found an example that demonstrates what I need. This implementation seems to only work with Scheduler.NewThread. My new problem is that I cant test this implementation at all since test scheduler seems to be CurrentThread.

My Console App EXAMPLE code:

```
var otherThreadScheduler = Scheduler.NewThread; 
cancel = otherThreadScheduler.Schedule(
    TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1),
    recursive =>
        {
            lock (obj)
            {

                Console.WriteLine(
                    "Processing Data - Thread ID = " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);

                var t = new Task(
                    () =>
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(
                                "Hi I'm the task on thread {0}",
                                Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);

                            Thread.Sleep(2000);
                        });

                t.Start();

                Console.WriteLine(
                    "Processing Data Waiting for it to finish - Thread ID = "
                    + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);

                t.Wait();
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Processing Data finished - Thread ID = " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);

            recursive(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
        });

cancel2 = otherThreadScheduler.Schedule(
    TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1),
    recursive =>
        {
            lock (obj)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Processing Detection - Thread ID = " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
                Thread.Sleep(10000);
            }

            recursive(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
        });
```

The reason this isnt testable is that the task in my real code is mockable so I mock it to loop until i signal it to stop but since my code does task.Wait(), my current thread blocks so I can never signal the task to return. The point of all that was to simulate a long running data collection and verify that the change detection does not fire.

So my question is: Is there a more elegant solution to my needs?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `Task.Wait` and block the current thread,

it might be better to write the completion code as a continuation.
i.e., use `Task.ContinueWith(_ => recursive(...))`.